is there any Openssl 3.x API for enabling and disabling FIPS mode?
i'm checking to see if there is any API or mechanism to enable or disable the FIPS Mode during the run time.
Currently the only way to change the FIPS mode is to enable the algorithm_sect (default_properties = fips=yes)
EVP_default_properties_enable_fips(null, 1) doesnt work and only the changes in the openssl.cnf is given priority.
Thanks ,
Zoeb.

What do you mean by EVP_default_properties_enable_fips() doesn't work? This should have the same effect as setting fips=yes in the config file.

FIPS mode is not getting enabled and non-fips algos still continue to work...
